# pass a date/date-time in the url for API with php

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest, url

I have created some API for my wordpress plugin. For example, I managed to make the API that finds a specific subscriber via url:

```
/id/2
```

This works for me. Now I was trying to do something like:

```
/data/2020-02-02
```

Maybe even with the time

```
/data/2020-02-02 13:27:11
```

but I can't do it.
i used this for the id and it works:

```
register_rest_route('cp/v1', '/logcaptiveportal/(?P<id>\d+)', [
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_userid_log',
]);
```

Comment: when using get api you can pass your data like this https://someaddress/api?id=1&date=2020-12-12

Comment: `\d+` matches digits only.